# How to make the f.select rails selected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, selected

My code:

```
<%= f.select :area, options_for_select([['a','a'],['b','b'],['c','c']]), {}, {:class => 'span3 controls controls-row'}, :selected => params[:area] %>
```

The result is:

```
ArgumentError in Users#edit
Showing /home/airson/rails_projects/friends_of_local/app/views/users/edit.html.erb where line #17 raised:
wrong number of arguments (5 for 4)
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Could you paste whole edit.html.erb template?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

No need to use `:selected` just pass your `params[:area]` alone to options_for_select as a second argument:

```
<%= f.select :area, 
    options_for_select([['a','a'],['b','b'],['c','c']], params[:area]),
    {}, { :class => 'span3 controls controls-row' } %>
```

The last value of your `params[:area]` will be selected.

Hope it helps ; )

Answer (score 16):

You should pass `:selected` option to `options_for_select` method, like this:

```
<%= f.select :area, options_for_select([['a','a'],['b','b'],['c','c']], :selected => params[:area]), {}, { :class => 'span3 controls controls-row' } %>
```

Answer (score 2):

The above answers didn't work for me on Rails 6. 
This is what worked. [Copied from one of the answers on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/rails/comments/6ek5mh/how_to_set_selected_value_on_form_field_load/dibf09c/)

```
= f.select(:results, options_for_select(['Accepted', 'Not Accepted', 'Rejected', 'Acc', 'Rej', 'Information Only', 'N/A'], selected: @report.results || nil), { include_blank: "Select Result" }, { class: 'form-control select2', style: 'width: 100%;'})
```

Comment: Worked in Rails 5.0, too.

Answer (score 1):

Below is what worked for me using f.select with custom names and values including a blank field while using the Ransack search. Thanks to mayorsanmayor's example for getting me started in the right direction. This also works for rails 5.1.7.

```
                <%= f.select(:status_eq, options_for_select([ ["Verified", "verified"], ["Non Verified","notVerified"]], selected: @q.status_eq || nil), {:include_blank => "Select Status"}, {class: 'form-control'}) %>
```