# Rails select - selected value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a rails form I am using a select tag for the param:contrat

this is my code

```
<%= f.label :contrat, "Type de contrat", class: "jobs-newtitles-two-half" %><br>

<%= f.select(:contrat, [["CDI", 1], ["CDD", 2], ["Contrat de Travail Temporaire ou d’intérim", 3], ["Freelance", 4], ["Stage", 5]], {}, {class: "form-control form-two-half"}) %>
```

when i choose for example CDI as contrat in the select list and submit form and go to the show page i have 1 instead of CDI why is this

this is my show page

```
Type de contrat: <%= @job.contrat %>
```

but instead of getting Type de contrat: CDI i get Type de contrat: 1

Comment: I really not understand your problem. What do you want? do you want to get "CDI" instead "1" from selected after submit that ? CDI is text of selected not value of selected.

Comment: I have explain more look at the the question now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code :

```
<%= f.select(:contrat, [["CDI", 1], ["CDD", 2], ["Contrat de Travail Temporaire ou d’intérim", 3], ["Freelance", 4], ["Stage", 5]], {}, {class: "form-control form-two-half"}) %>
```

It will save `1` to database instead `"CDI"`, so on your show page you have `1`.

If you want "CDI" on your show page, there are many ways to do it.

---

## first (not recommend, it can breaks a clean MVC approach)

Add this into your model

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base

 def contrat_string
   ## if string data type of contrat, you should quote e.g if contrat == "1"
   if contrat == 1
     "CDI"
   elsif contrat == 2
     "CDD"
   elsif contrat == 3
     "Contrat de Travail Temporaire ou d’intérim"
   elsif contrat == 4
    "Freelance"
   else
    "Stage"
   end
 end

end
```

And on show page

```
Type de contrat: <%= @job.contrat_string %>
```

---

## second

Add method into your helper

```
module ApplicationHelper

  def contrat_to_s(contrat)
  ## if string data type of contrat, you should quote e.g if contrat == "1"
    if contrat == 1
      "CDI"
    elsif contrat == 2
      "CDD"
    elsif contrat == 3
      "Contrat de Travail Temporaire ou d’intérim"
    elsif contrat == 4
      "Freelance"
    else
      "Stage"
    end
  end

end
```

And on show page

```
Type de contrat: <%= contrat_to_s(@job.contrat) %>
```

---

## third (recommend)

You can put the definition of an array in `/config/locales/your_language.yml`

Example if you are using english `en.yml`

```
en:
  contrat_strings: 
      1: CDI
      2: CDD
      3: Contrat de Travail Temporaire ou d’intérim 
      4: Freelance
      5: Stage
```

On your helper e.g `application_helper.rb`

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def contrat_selects 
    I18n.t(:contrat_strings).map { |key, value| [ value, key ] } 
  end

  def contrat_views(value)
     I18n.t(:contrat_strings)[value]
  end
end
```

On show page

```
Type de contrat: <%= contrat_views(@job.contrat) %>
```

On form

```
<%= f.select :contrat, contrat_selects %>
```

Note : I have tested. All works for me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Whatever the type of contrat selected i get in the show page Type de contrat: Stage

Comment: @userails : does it works ? , I have updated my answer add another ways.

Comment: for the second approach i still get the same results. I havn't try the Third approach yet

Comment: Are you sure?, what is data type of contrat? I have tested and all works on rails 3.2.xx and 4.1.x.

Comment: Why you have string data type but you put number 1,2,3,4 and 5 instead of word "CDI", "CDD" etc for save to database? try to change with integer data type if you still use number on select or still using string data type and adding quote to if..else logic, example `if contrat == "1" .... elsif contrat == "2"`

Comment: Ok it work now thank you for your help i have another question for you if you permit how can i prevent users from changing the data of select manualy in browser (ex : change the option value to "hack" and the contrat name to another words

Comment: @userails : You can use [validates_inclusion_of](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_inclusion_of). So value change with user can't save to database and will show validation message..

Answer (score 0):

this should work :

```
<%= f.select :contrat, 
    options_for_select([["CDI", 1], ["CDD", 2], ["Contrat de Travail Temporaire ou d’intérim", 3], ["Freelance", 4], ["Stage", 5]]], params[:contrat]),
    {}, { :class => 'form-control form-two-half' } %>
```

[How to make the f.select rails selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18100834/how-to-make-the-f-select-rails-selected)

Comment: still get the same results